# How to find NPM package on Unpkg

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, systemjs

I'm trying to include an unpkg link to a particular NPM package '[Angular Calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-calendar)' in my system.config.js file so I can run my site on a server without building every time.

I don't know how to find the link. The system.config.js file on the [example](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink) site of the NPM package shows it referencing npm, which to me means locally. I've tried that and it didnt work.

```
 'angular-calendar': 'npm:angular-calendar@0.21.3/dist/umd/angular-calendar.js',
```

I just get an error saying error loading ... as "angular-calendar"

Any ideas? Am I looking at the problem correctly? I'm trying to run my site on a server, without building. So I need to link to all the dependencies in system.config.js. I don't know how to link to third party packages. I understand that if it's an NPM package, there is an unpgk link. I just don't know how to find it.

Thanks

Comment: unpkg doesn't have any directory, listing, or search functionality at this point in time.  However, all they do is wrap [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) so you can explore and search for packages there and use the same name in unpkg

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are some more docs on their homepage at https://unpkg.com

**To get a specific version**:

If I enter the url: `https://unpkg.com/angular-calendar@0.21.3`
It would serve: `https://unpkg.com/angular-calendar@0.21.3/dist/umd/angular-calendar.js`

**To get the latest version**:

If I enter the url: `https://unpkg.com/angular-calendar`
It would serve: `https://unpkg.com/angular-calendar@0.23.6/bundles/angular-calendar.umd.js`

**To browse the files in a package**:

If you append a `/` to the url, it will list all the files in the package, ie.

`https://unpkg.com/angular-calendar@0.21.3/` will list all the files in that particular package.

Answer (score 4):

There is no official way to search for UNPKG packages but there is a third part website https://unpkg.webutils.app/

You can search for packages and directly copy the unpkg link

Comment: @Prid It should be working now